# Force to send transaction ignoring failing status web3js 4.x.x

Tags: web3js

I have upgraded to web3 4.x.x, but I can not force to send a transaction ignoring its status cuz I have a batch of transactions and I need to broadcast all, thanks in advance.

```
let txRaw = "...";
const broadcastResult = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txRaw, 
{
    checkRevertBeforeSending: false,
    options: {
        checkRevertBeforeSending: false
    }
});
```

Log:

```
broadcast with key... got error TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
/home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:57
            error = new web3_errors_1.TransactionRevertInstructionError(_reason.reason, _reason.signature, transactionReceiptFormatted, _reason.data);
                    ^

TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at /home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:57:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:20:12)
    at getTransactionError (/home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/utils/get_transaction_error.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:441:100)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/lc/Project/SC/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  innerError: undefined,
  reason: 'execution reverted: SM/PF',
  signature: '0x08c379a0',
  receipt: undefined,
  data: '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005534d2f5046000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  code: 402
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed the 2nd parameter:

```
public sendSignedTransaction<ReturnFormat extends DataFormat = typeof DEFAULT_RETURN_FORMAT>(
    transaction: Bytes,
    returnFormat: ReturnFormat = DEFAULT_RETURN_FORMAT as ReturnFormat,
    options?: SendTransactionOptions,
) {
    return rpcMethodsWrappers.sendSignedTransaction(this, transaction, returnFormat, options);
}
```

So, change to this will ignore the revert status:

```
const broadcastResult = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(resMap.get(key), "hex",
{
    checkRevertBeforeSending: false
});
```